# Why is it that when a redux state is an array it does not trigger useEffect()? and what are ways to trigger it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, redux

I have this problem where to update a redux state that is an array I have to change it to a non array value to be able to trigger useEffect()

for example :

I have this reducer, as you can see it is an array

```
export const markerReducer = (value = [], action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MarkerReducer/SET":
      return action.value;
    default:
      return value;
  }
};
```

To update this and also triggering useEffect() I have to do this :

```
dispatch({
   type: "MarkerReducer/SET",
   value: null,
});

await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));

dispatch({
   type: "MarkerReducer/SET",
   value: _markers, // - new array value
});
```

This triggers useEffect() and will work, however since my UI has some colors when it has arrays when it updates it looks wonky and glitchy and I don't think it would be a good user experience.

Am I doing this wrong? what are ways to update it by just putting in an array with a different value and triggering useEffect()?

I also know I could just trigger another state to rerender the entire page but I think that is bad practice.

Edit:

UseEffect is setup this way:

```
  const markers: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    return state.markerState;
  });

  useEffect(() => { // - not triggering
    ...
  }, [markers]);
```

_markers value is populated this way:

```
...
   const i = store.getState().lyricIndexState;
   let _markers = markers;
   for (let m = 0; m < _markers.length; m++) {
        if (
          _markers[m].start_index == i ||
          _markers[m].end_index == i ||
          (i > _markers[m].start_index && i < _markers[m].end_index)
        ) {
          if (type == "add") {
            _markers[m][i] = `${store.getState().lyricState[i]}:${
              store.getState().AudioCurrentTimeState
            }`;
            added = true;
          } else {
            _markers[m][i] = -1;
            added = true;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please share what your `useEffect()` call looks like and how you're populating the `_markers` array value?

Comment: I've added the implementation of useEffect() and _markers @nick-parsons

Comment: `let _markers = markers` is most likely your problem. This doesn't create a copy of the `markers` state, it just creates a new variable called `_markers` and makes it point to the same array in memory to what `markers` is pointing to. So any modifications of `_markers` ends up also modifying `markers`, so you're modifying your state directly which won't work when you try and set that new state value (as the new value is the same as the state old value). You need to do a _deep copy_ of your array, see: [Updating Arrays in State](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state)

Comment: @nick-parsons thanks, I think this is the right answer. Could you put it is an answer so I could mark this thread done?